# Partition record processor on csv data error. Invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I am getting csv files after hitting an api (using invokeHTTP), after that i pass it to a Partition record Processor whose configuration is shown below:[Partition record processor config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxj4F.jpg)

But i am getting this error :[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFlPk.png)

Line 81 seems to be the problem. Below are the lines 80 (which is not giving the error) and line 81 (which is giving the error):

**LINE 80**: "12823279995108993","12823279995125025","","BUS_IN","2020-10-17 04:46:39","2020-10-17 11:20:00","ONWARD","BS:MOBILEWEB#droidapp",2,"S18:S17","TENTATIVE_EXPIRED","","","",false,"",false,"","","abc","MALE",21,43860744,91987654321,"abc@gmail.com","","19023","Expresso","46","14118149","A/C Seater / Sleeper (2+2)","Delhi","733","20328326","01204760001","2020-10-17 14:00:00","2020-10-17 11:20:00","1377","Kanpur (Uttar Pradesh)","20673108","2020-10-17 22:00:00","2020-10-17 22:00:00",0,false,1236.90,1178.00,0.00,0.00,1011.19,1236.90,0,"","",0,58.90,0.00,"911edfa4b1d6f0055722993401020100","INR",1178.00,"INR","0:12:100:0;12:24:50:0;24:-1:20:0","INR","","",0,"",1,"",0,"",0,"4:-1:10:0"

**LINE 81:** "12823279989247850","12823279989257690","","BUS_IN","2020-10-17 04:46:38","2020-10-17 09:30:00","ONWARD","BS:MOBILEWEB#droidapp",1,"L4","TENTATIVE_EXPIRED","","","",false,"",false,"","","bcd","FEMALE",22,44156809,91123456789,"bcd@gmail.com","","18599","abc travels and Cargo","106123","15476131","A/C Seater / Sleeper (2+1)","Surat","473","21765854","9799678467","2020-10-17 09:30:00","2020-10-17 09:30:00","78027","Gorakhpur (uttar pradesh)","19252221","2020-10-19 00:49:00","2020-10-19 00:49:00",0,false,2650.00,2500.00,0.00,0.00,2146.00,2650.00,0,"","",0,125.00,0.00,"9113aebbb1d6f005e2483f9f02020100","INR",2500.00,"INR","0:24:100:0;24:48:70:0;48:72:50:0;72:166:40:0;166:-1:30:0","INR","","",0,"",0,"",0,"",0,""

I am not allowed to change the schema or fields in any way from the api side, so i have to add some processor in Nifi to overcome this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Hard to read, inaccessible, not indexed.

Answer (score 0):

@Prathik

You are going to have to figure out which character is invalid.   You may not even see it, for example hidden return/newline character within a string are possible not seen when viewing in text format.

Once you can see which character is triggering the error, you should be able to use ReplaceText processor, or UpdateRecord processor to make the adjustment to the flowfile before sending it to PartitionRecord.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just like the way you said it, i am unable to find anything wrong in the csv data when viewed in text format. Is there any other way to view the file which can make the spotting of errors much simpler, as the csv data has 1000s of line of data.

Comment: Did you run a test without that line to see if error was occurring in other lines?   i dont trust the text we see in this post, so you would have to look at the original source file with a text editor and look for something.  One other thing:  its an error from partition record, so what is the schema?  maybe the error is in partition field...  also maybe the "" (empty) is invalid against schema too...

Comment: Maybe try ValidateRecord or ValidateCSV to get rid of (or separately process) invalid lines